# In React, does a list of memo component get rendered if they are inside the map function called from the a list state?

Tags: reactjs

Assuming I have a memoized child component:

```
function Child({number}){
     return <div> {number} </div>;
}
export React.memo(child)
```

The Child component only gets rerender if the number props is changed.

Now, I put the Child component inside the Parent component. The parent component is as of following:

```
function Parents(){
    const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([1,2,3,4,5,6]);

    return (
            <>
              numbers.map((number,index)=>{
               <Child key={index} number={number}> 
              }
            </>
        )
   }
```

So, in this case, the Child components are generated inside a loop over the numbers array. However, the child components are memoized. In case when only one number is changed in the array, for example, if we change `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` to [`1,2,111111,4,5,6]`. The third number goes from 3 to 111111. Now, does the every child element get rerendered, or only the third child elements get rerender?

Comment: You need a unique key when using map
<Child key={number} />

Comment: @HugoMallet used index since number isn't always unique

Comment: Alright then unless length or order change, children shouldn't be re-rendered

Comment: @HugoMallet even if i change the number inside the state array?

Comment: If you change a number, the related component will be re-rendered because its prop number changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, *only the third child will be re-rendered*, as the props for the other children will be the same

You can check this for yourself using the following example:

```js
import {memo, useState} from 'react'



const Child = memo(({number}) => {
  console.log('re-render', number);
  return <div>{number}</div>;
})

export default function App() {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([1,2,3,4,5,6]);

  return (
    <>
      {numbers.map((number,index)=>
        <Child number={number} /> )
      }

      <button onClick={() => {
        setNumbers(prev => {
         prev[2] = 111;
         return [...prev];
        })
      }}>
        click
      </button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: prev[1] = 111? not prev[2] = 111? Third index

Comment: yep. But it works for any index

Comment: if i don't memo the Child component, is the React diff algorithm smart enough to know which Child component to rerender, in this case, the third Child component?

Comment: No, because you have changed the state of the parent, so all the children will be re-rendered if they are not memoized.